# How to set properties in a xaml to a maximum value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, size

I'm working on a `UserControl`, which has some labels, checkboxes, ....

In order to configure that usercontrol, some styles are used, as you can see here:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
```

This is great in order to avoid those fonts and margins getting too large, but when the usercontrol gets smaller, those values make the usercontrol unreadable:

[image]

Is there a way to use a maximum value for such a property, something like:

```
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="max(16)"/>
```

Comment: One of the options you have is to use a simple value converter, which takes actual height and adjusts font value based on available space. However, based on your screenshot the font size is not the issue, the container that holds checkbox with label is. My suggestion is to set MinHeight value to the container, so that it will never get smaller then the font size and not break UX

Comment: @Demon: the Minheight is not an option, as the window I've created only works on desktop computers, but not on laptops

Comment: You could use a viewbox to scale the content

Comment: @Dominique what does desktop anyhing to do with xaml? if you are using wpf then there is a minHeight property for every UIElement. in case of the Xamaring/UWP/MAUI there are flexible settings for that as well. For example : <Stackpanel MinHeight="55"> <CheckBox/><Label/></StackPanel> here the Stackpanel is the container for your ui elements

Comment: @Demon: I mean that I have a UserControl, which I can see entirely when working with a desktop computer. However, the screen on a laptop is smaller, and as a result, as the fontsize does not seem to decrease, the UserControl becomes unreadable, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @Dominique Laptops utilize DPI scaling, this is completely different question and solutions to resolve it (if that's the case). As I mentioned either you ensure that the container has enough space for the FontSize you want OR you make a converter for font size that will calculate the size of font for each element based on available space/user setting

Answer (score -1):

I guess your responsive design is wrong then; maybe you should use a WrapPanel to use the horizontal space as well. Also it seems that the parent of the usercontrol controls the height of the usercontrol, this feels wrong, the usercontrol has a list of checkboxes so it should be auto size.

But if you really want to scale down everything you could indeed use a ViewBox like Andy stated.